# How do I get my react client to connect to the right server that heroku provides for the express backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a react client that uses a fetch request to the express host. I cannot get them to connect once deployed to Heroku.

I have tried using `"/"`, I have tried using the URL for the app itself, can't get it to work. Code snippet below.

Client:

```
const response = await fetch("https://murmuring-spire-37547.herokuapp.com/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: messages,
      }),
    }
```

Express:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { message } = req.body;
    console.log(message, 'message')
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `${message}`,
        max_tokens: 100,
        temperature: 0.5,
      });
      res.json({
        message: response.data.choices[0].text,
      })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3080;
```

link to github repo below. Any help is appreciated.

https://github.com/gmhartman/chatbot

Comment: Is there any error on your client and server side? Check the logs